# How to make columns editable or readOnly?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Is there a way in sharepoint 2007 to make columns as readonly or editable depending on the user roles accessing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this link where you can get the user group of the person
http://morshemesh.blogspot.ru/2012/07/getting-all-groups-of-user-with.html

then you would just disable the other fields depending on the usergroup you want them to be disabled.

This would make use of SPServices and JQuery.

Comment: You did not answer how to disable the fields though.